# view favorite tag questions rather than top questions

Tags: support, homepage

When I login into Stackoverflow, I would like to see a list of questions which are selected on the basis of my `favorite tags` rather than viewing my top questions.

Is this possible? If not, I feel that this is an option which should be provided to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already happens after changes to the homepage made in November 2010.  [See this blog post.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) for full details.

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a
> list of the last 3,000 active
> questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for
>   reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
>
> Next, apply the following score
> formula to the remaining questions:
>
> - your interesting tags  +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
> - your top 40 scoring tags   maximum of +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
> - question score         +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
> - total answer score         -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
> - number of answers          -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
> - number of views            -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
> - question last activity date    -1 × (seconds / 15)
>
> Count it all up and take the top 90 by
> score.
>
> We also mix in a few random questions
> from the last 3,000 — 10% (9) for
> logged in users and 20% (18) for
> anonymous users.

Also, see [this question for a community maintained list of recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

This formula applies to questions on http://stackoverflow.com if you browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions then the questions are filtered based on the tab selection.

Comment: Barry, I can not understand how it works. I clicked on QUESTION button and the list seems to not related to my favorite tags at all

Comment: @Maksee - click on the StackOverflow image or browse to http://stackoverflow.com The questions will then be filtered as per above. i.e 90% your tags and 10% random.

Comment: Barry, look like something's wrong or I miss the point. My home page contains reverse to that, about 10% of questions containing my tags. I have about 7 tags and only tenth of questions have yellow background (and sure tags).